# Exactly what operations can only be done on the user interface thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface

So I understand that any changes to the UI need to be on the main thread for an Android application. And also, you should use other threads to do work so that the UI doesn't freeze up. But some of the work I want to do is preparing UI elements which will be shown later on. I want to get those things ready on a separate thread and then enable a button once its done - that way the user won't be able to access it until it's ready BUT they'll be able to use the main page quickly.

Exactly what operations count as changing the UI? I want to do as much preparation in the background so that the first part of the app ready can be shown ASAP while other parts are still loading.

For example, it seems like findViewById is fine, but what about creating/modifying Views, setting listeners, setId, setEnabled and so on? If I newly create a Button which hasn't been added to a parent, can I setText on it in a background thread?

Comment: This seems to be purely andriod specific. Remove other tags

Comment: I think only creating/modifying Views must be done in main thread, while setting listeners could be done in any threads.

Comment: Okay, but what counts as modifying? Is setText modifying but setOnClickListener isn't? What about setId and so on? And what if I'm modifying a newly created button that isn't shown yet? I was hoping to get a precise answer.

Comment: Setting a listener to your view(s) is normally not an expensive task therefore it can go to `UIThread`. `What operations count as changing the UI?` changing color, text, position, orientation, gravity, size etc.

Comment: I cannot find official listing of actions for modifying UI, but basically what make the appearance of UI changes are actions that modify UI. If you want to be sure you can test what you want to do in a separate thread and see if it dies. I just experiment setting id of a fragment view versus setting title of the fragment's activity. Set id has no problem while set activity title dies immediately.

Comment: Okay, and changing those things counts even if the views aren't visible to the user? I guess inflating layouts also counts? It's annoying having to use the main thread to change things which can't even be seen or interacted with yet.

Comment: Inflating layouts belongs to "creating" category. Regardless if your view is visible or not visible you are still performing an operation so YES.

Comment: karnok, just tried a TextView that isn't attached to any parent view can freely setText() in a separate thread, while one that's attached will die from ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException.

Comment: I think modifying the UI means something that results in a synchronous call to onDraw()